# LOAD DATA INPATH loads same CSV-base data into two different and external Hive tables

Tags: csv, azure, hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight

I have two CSV-files that I uploaded to the Azure Blob Storage within HDInsight. I can upload these two files to the cluster without problems. I then create two Hive-tables with...

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hive_table1(id int, age string, date string...) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\;' STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '/user/hive/warehouse'
```

Similar syntax goes for the other table.

Now I want to load the first CSV-file into the first table and the second CSV-file into the second table (resulting in non-corresponding columns).

I use...

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '/file/file1.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE hive_table1;
```

...and am able to load the CSV-file data into the first table. *But*..., not only is the first data set loaded into the first Hive table, it *also* loads the exact same file's data into the *second* Hive table.

Obviously, I *only* want to have the first data set loaded into one table and the second *distinct* data set *only* into the other table.

Can anyone help pointing out errors or contribute with a possible solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just need to specify a different 'LOCATION' for the second table. When you do the 'LOAD DATA', Hive is actually copying data into that path. If both tables have the same 'LOCATION', they will share the same data.

Comment: You are absolutely right! This solved the issue. I wasn't aware of this behavior as this is the first time, working with HDInsight, Hadoop, Hive etc. I upvoted your answer Rick but since my rep is below 15 points, it won't be visible. Thanks for taking the time and making the effort to help me. This also goes for you Farooque and Sathiyan. Thanks to everybody! Highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your location is what creating problem. You have given same location for both the tables. As the tables are external the file will be created directly under your path.

Also `LOAD DATA INPATH '/file/file1.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE hive_table1;` will overwrites the already existing file. This is what happening with your tables. As Farooque mentioned for different tables the location should be unique to get the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are creating `external` table and creating 2 tables having single files each.

You have to follow the simple steps as below:

**Create table**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hive_table1(id int, age string, date string...) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '/user/hive/warehouse/table1_dir/'
```

**Copy file to HDFS location**

```
hdfs dfs -put '/file/file1.csv' '/user/hive/warehouse/table1_dir/'
```

Similary for second table

**Create table**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hive_table2(id int, age string, date string...) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '/user/hive/warehouse/table2_dir/'
```

**Copy file to HDFS location**

```
hdfs dfs -put '/file/file2.csv' '/user/hive/warehouse/table2_dir/'
```

**Note:** If you are using more than one table, then their location should be unique.